# Rails POST Form Don't Send Full of Data to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine-plugins

I work on beginner level web application which is save off days request of users by using simple form.

Here is codes

views/days/index.html.erb

```html
  <%= form_for @daysoff, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.date_field :offdate, id: 'altField' %>
  <p> User holding the fort / Yerine bakicak kisi

    <%= f.collection_select(:assign_id, @people, :id, :name) %> </p>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    <% end %>
```

controllers/days_controller.rb

```ruby
class DaysController < ApplicationController
  unloadable

    def index
    @people = User.all
    @user = User.current

    @daysoff = Daysoff.new

#    params[:daysoff][:user_id] = @user.id

  end

  def create

    off_dates = params["daysoff"]["offdate"].try(:split,',')

    off_dates.each do |off_date|
      @days_off = Daysoff.new
      @days_off.offdate = Date.strptime(off_date.strip, "%m/%d/%Y")
      @days_off.user_id = User.current
      @days_off.assign_id = params["assign_id"]
      @days_off.status = 0
      @days_off.save!
    end

    redirect_to "/days_off_redmine", :flash => { :success => "Istek gonderildi." }

  end
```

There is no any model validation.

Database migration file.

```ruby
class CreateDaysoffs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :daysoffs do |t|
      t.date :offdate
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :assign_id
      t.boolean :status
    end
  end
end
```

When i try to fill and post form, 
Offdates and status filling correctly but user_id and assign_id insert db as NULL.

---

```
+----+------------+---------+-----------+--------+
| id | offdate    | user_id | assign_id | status |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+--------+
|  1 | 2015-07-14 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
|  2 | 2015-07-15 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
|  3 | 2015-07-14 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
|  4 | 2015-07-15 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
|  5 | 2015-07-22 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
|  6 | 2015-07-23 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
|  7 | 2015-07-21 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
|  8 | 2015-07-22 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
|  9 | 2015-07-21 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
| 10 | 2015-07-22 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
| 11 | 2015-07-21 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
| 12 | 2015-07-22 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
| 13 | 2015-07-29 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
| 14 | 2015-07-30 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
| 15 | 2015-07-29 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
| 16 | 2015-07-30 |    NULL |      NULL |      0 |
+----+------------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

Why this occur like that?

Comment: You have a `user_id` in your form and in controller you use `User.current` which is nil. That doesn't seem consistent :). Also you set `assign_id` to `params["assign_id"]` which is also nil because it's not in your form or is it somewhere else?.

Comment: @JackWatson please check collection field. Im using webrick, it put logs to stdout and when i send request, i see my all field is full. I think there is no error at the form what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Skipping the fact that code looks really bad...

form attributes are present in `params[:daysoff]`, you would need to get to fields by it, for example:

to get assign_id by `params[:daysoff][:assign_id]`

`@days_off.user_id = User.current` should be rather: `@days_off.user_id = User.current.id`

or @days_off should have in model class added

`belongs_to :user` and it would be working fine, unless User.current is nil